# CSS Dropdown menu doesn't work in IE 8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

i have a dropdown menu in css, it works fine in Chrome, FireFox, but not IE8, i haven't checked it in IE6/7. but it seems hopeless.
my site at [HERE](http://blackknight.byethost7.com/test/).
The dropdown menu is the black one.
i think the problem is with the :hover, try searching around something like #button .a:hover, etc... but get no luck.
I hope you can help. the css file is [HERE](http://blackknight.byethost7.com/test/menu/menu_style.css)

Thank you sirs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you have not included a [doctype](http://hsivonen.iki.fi/doctype/) on your website.

Because you haven't included a doctype, your page is rendering in [**Quirks mode**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode) in IE8:

> Quirks mode is a rendering mode used
>   by some web browsers for the sake of
>   maintaining backward compatibility
>   with web pages designed for older
>   browsers or coded without standards
>   conformance.

Add these two lines to the very top of your file:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
```

If you add in that magical doctype line, your drop down works in IE8 *and* IE7.

---

You should move this part of your code to within your `<body>` tag.

```
<span style="float:right;margin-top:10px;">
<a href=?lang=vn><img src="img/vn.gif"></img></a> 
<a href=?lang=en><img src="img/us.gif"></img></a>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
</span>
```

Also, you can change it to something like this:

```
<div style="position:absolute; top:10px; right: 10px">
    <a href="?lang=vn"><img src="img/vn.gif"></img></a> 
    <a href="?lang=en"><img src="img/us.gif"></img></a>
</div>
```

Comment: @thirtydot, thank you sirs, i did the same as your post but everything is still the, i hope you can have a look at my code again. Thank you sirs

Comment: It didn't work because the very first character in your file is a backtick (like this: `\``). Get rid of that, and it will work. Also, you should remove the whitespace from the top of the file.

Comment: Oops, it's not actually a backtick - my eyes decieved me. You have the bytes `ef bb bf ef bb bf` as the first characters in your file. This is a [byte order mark (BOM)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark). You need to save your file without that.

Comment: @thirtydot , thank you sirs, i save it as UTF-8 without BOM with Notepad++, but that strange character keep showing there.

Comment: Are you sure you selected `Encoding` -> `Encode in UTF-8 without BOM`? Are you also 1000% sure you uploaded the changed file?

Comment: @thirtydot @i'm 1000% sure about this. i use filezilla to edit so i can see any change in the script

Comment: "i use filezilla to edit" - You mean you're changing your page using Filezilla? I hope not. All I can say is, I've saved your page without a BOM in Notepad++, and the BOM is gone and your page works. *Somehow* you're still putting the BOM in the file.

Comment: @thirtydot thank you sirs, i see why the BOM is being there all the time, it's because of some php script before it, actually i have some php script at the beginning of my page and then [echo $html], that explain all. Thank you sir. thank for spending your time. You make my day.

Comment: @Ryo: Another "solution" is to add this meta tag: `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />`

Comment: @Ryo: It works with a BOM. The problem is that you somehow have a "double BOM", which is confusing IE.

Answer (score 1):

When this sort of thing happens - go to Tools --> Compatibility Mode ; and make sure it's off. I have had similar issue and switching that off made my menu work properly (where it wasn't working at all).